# Cannot add datepicker to C# .NET gridview cell

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datepicker

I have a web site written in C# .Net using Web Forms.  I have a gridview with three columns, the first one being the “Date” field.  I’ve added a blank row to the gridview and set the EditIndex to that row.  I want the user to be able to click in that editable Date cell and have the datepicker calendar display.

My code:
ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="TaskGridViewAB" runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    OnRowUpdating="TaskGridViewAB_RowUpdating">
</asp:GridView>
```

I get the data for this grid from an Oracle database.
I add an empty row to the results (this all works):

```
sql = " - my SELECT statement - "
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, Conn);
...
OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
//Add the blank row
DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
//Fill the table with the SELECT results 
oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

I believe this line is setup incorrectly:

```
string js = "$(function() { $('#" + TaskGridViewAB.ClientID + "').datepicker();  });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), js, true);
```

I also tried – this also did not work:

```
string js = "$(function() { $('#" + e.Row.Cells[0].ClientID + "').datepicker(); });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), js, true);
```

Note: I could replace the above two lines and assign the datepicker to a textbox I have and that DOES work, however I need the calendar in the gridview, not the textbox:

```
string js = "$(function() { $('#" + txtDate.ClientID + "').datepicker(); });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), js, true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I realize there are similar inquires regarding similar situations, but I've been unable to get this to work.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Gridview RowEditing that text box won't be available to find until you enter edit mode, and then it must be found in the RowEditing event

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try changing the selector. Instead of trying to figure out the id of the generated textbox just examine the markup and understand where exactly this textbox goes and how to pinpoint it with a single selector.

For example, I am going to assume that this textbox ended up in the last `tr`, and that it is the only `input` with type `text` in that row. It can be incorrect, but should illustrate the idea:

```
string js =
    "$(function() {" +
        "$('#" + txtDate.ClientID + " tr:last')" +
        ".find('input[type=\"text\"]')" +
        ".datepicker();" +
    "});";
```

Comment: Having the datepicker open in the text box is not a problem.  As I stated, that WORKS.  I only wrote to the text box to verify my JavaScript line was formatted correctly.  What I cannot do is have the datepicker open in my GridView.

Comment: @CrazyCat, yep, I understand that. However datepicker got to have a textbox to bind to, right? You create that textbox in this editable row that you append, in the date column. And now you need to pick that textbox (again, not a standalone one, the one inside the GridView) from the last row and bind datepicker to it. The answer is a suggestion on how to do it without trying to get the id of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

When combining JS/JQ with asp.net controls I always try to use Static ids or CSS classnames to locate elements.  It makes things far easier than having to deal with the id name mangling.

You didn't post the GridView aspx so I'm going to assume you are auto-generating columns.

Since you are using the row editing feature of the GridView I would find the Textbox and in the RowEditing event append or add to the CssClass:

```
    txtData.CssClass += " dtpkr"  // the string 'dtpkr' is arbitrary
```

Then you can do this in the jq:

```
    $(".dtpkr").datepicker();
```